# Sporadic HTTP 408 response on pages behind MS Forefront TMG 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-forefront-2010

I'm getting sporadic HTTP 408 responses when I try to load pages from my site.

The network is set up with Forefront acting as a proxy in front of the web server.  When I first load the page, it comes up normally.  If I immediately click another page in the site, it also comes up normally.

If I wait a couple of minutes before clicking anything, I get HTTP 408 in the browser.

TMG's log shows several entries:
Action - Result Code - Status

1. Closed Connection - 0x80074e21 FWX_E_ABORTIVE_SHUTDOWN: "A
   connection was abortively closed after one of the peers sent an RST
   packet."
2. Failed Connection Attempt - (no result code): "10060 A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because a connected host failed to respond."
3. Closed Connection - 0x80074e20 FWX_E_GRACEFUL_SHUTDOWN: "A connection was gracefully closed in an orderly shutdown process with a three-way FIN-initiated handshake."

On the web server itself, Resource Monitor shows that the TCP connection to Forefront expired shortly before the request that got the 408 response.

Is there a configuration setting that can be changed to avoid this?

Comment: Enabling tcp keepalives? http://blogs.technet.com/b/nettracer/archive/2010/06/03/things-that-you-may-want-to-know-about-tcp-keepalives.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're already using TMG 2010 SP2 (to rule out any already-fixed weirdness), it sounds more like there might be a network connectivity problem between it and the published server.